# How to display MYSQL COUNT horizontally

Tags: mysql, count

Hi I am trying to display COUNT result in horizontal way but to no success. Is there any easyway to do this?

I have this table (created in excel for demo purposes)

[image]

Now I want to display the result like this.

[image]

Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT store_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'hold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hold_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ship' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ship_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'return' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS return_count
FROM table
group by store_name
```

Comment: Ah yes, the famous CASE method. +1 :)

Comment: thank you so much.. i keep on exploring count but it turns out that I need SUM. Works perfectly!!!

Comment: @genpet: `COUNT()` works too. Just replace (example, 1st row) with: `COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'hold' THEN 1 END) AS hold_count`

Answer (score 2):

Use if clause inside sum-aggregate.

```
select store_name,
  sum(if(status='hold', 1, 0)) as 'hold',
  sum(if(status='ship', 1, 0)) as 'ship',
  sum(if(status='return', 1, 0)) as 'return'
from mytable
group by store_name;
```

Comment: Works as well, great! Thanks!